# Custom Relative Path In Asp.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, .net-core

Is there any possibility to have a custom relative path same as example at below:

In Razor:

```
<script src="%/scripts/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And Result:

```
<script src="/themes/default/scripts/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Define New PATH style same as `%/` or `*/` or `$/`

**Attention:** I KNOW ABOUT `~/` (default relative path). I'm talking about **how can I Define NEW ONE?**

Comment: can you try this <script type="text/javascript" src='@Url.Content("~/scripts/theme.js")'></script>

Comment: No. Please read what I said there. I said CUSTOM this is not CUSTOM. Define new one. Of course i KNOW about ~/. something new so i be able to define same as %/ or ^/ or */ .....

Comment: :D @hasan thank you. you didn't understand me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
Please take a looks how Microsoft had implement it at link below:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1c4b0fcdf38320b2f02c0bb7c31df5bd391ace07/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor/TagHelpers/UrlResolutionTagHelper.cs#L47

I had take a copy of this class and I renamed that to this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("link", Attributes = "[href^='%/']", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
[HtmlTargetElement("script", Attributes = "[src^='%/']")]
....
public class ThemeUrlResolutionTagHelper : TagHelper
{
   /*Implement tag helper here*/
}
```

And before creating trimmed string I insert my Theme URL

```
url = url.Remove(start, 2).Insert(start, $"~/themes/{Theme.Key}/");
var trimmedUrl = CreateTrimmedString(url, start);
```

And I changed the ~ to % in `FindRelativeStart` method

```
// Before doing more work, ensure that the URL we're looking at is app-relative.
if (url[start] != '%' || url[start + 1] != '/')
{
    return -1;
}
```

And Done!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `~` (tilde).   There is no `%` operator for paths:

```
 <script src="~/scripts/theme.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: please take a looks again to example. i said CUSTOM. ~/ it's return you wwwroot and i want to have a custom one. % it was a example to have a new CUSTOM one. I want to point to the specific PATH.